# SSMS not coloring tables, columns and variables

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I use SSMS 2012 v11.0.5058.0.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173443.aspx) says "System table, view, or table-valued function" should have green color. I'm used to have green color in variables and a few other token types too. But my SSMS keeps them black as raw values.

I followed [Change Font Color, Size, and Style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173754.aspx) and tried to set default, but it didn't solve. I also tried to set them manually but didn't find them to select.

Any idea what may be the issue?

This happens in both cases of opening an `.sql` file or having SSMS create a select query for a table. Even when there are `[]` around the column name. It remains even after restarting Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I was unable to fix color. I just installed standalone SSMS 2016 and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Colors are controlled via the options dialog box, which you linked to in your question.

Check the following, to see what it shows in the "Sample" box:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Tools - Options - Environment - Fonts and Colors, and select the Teal, Green or imitate the custom Aquamarine color for the "Identifier" items.

Answer (score -3):

Are you sure that you have intellisense enabled?
You can see general information about it under Tools -> Options. I'd check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173743.aspx) for more info.

Comment: unfortunately this is not related to Intellisense.  Intellisense shows objects, etc, in response to keystrokes.  The question is about the colors of text in the query window.